# PHPUnit reports a PHPUnit_Framework_Exception

Tags: phpunit, symfony

I added a simple test to a bundle.

As suggested in the manual I tried to have PHPUnit load the configuration with:

```
phpunit -c /app
```

phpunit.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit
    backupGlobals               = "false"
    backupStaticAttributes      = "false"
    colors                      = "true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions = "true"
    processIsolation            = "false"
    stopOnFailure               = "false"
    syntaxCheck                 = "false"
    bootstrap                   = "bootstrap.php.cache" >

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

The error message I get is:

```
root@h0x03:/var/www/fi/FrontendIntegrator# phpunit -c app/
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message 'Neither "Project Test Suite.php" nor "Project Test Suite.php" could be opened.' in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Skeleton/Test.php:102
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(157): PHPUnit_Util_Skeleton_Test->__construct('Project Test Su...', '')
#1 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#2 /usr/bin/phpunit(49): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Skeleton/Test.php on line 102
```

PHPUnit apparently loads the file and tries to find a PHP-file named after the test suites name. I cannot find any information on why it does so or how such a file should look like.

Comment: First you need to enter into project directory. Then only the command will work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like PHPUnit tries to find a file named after the name-attribute of the testsuite-tag

1. if it either **cannot find any tests** (wrong naming or wrong directory) or
2. if there is a **fatal error** occuring in a test-script; which occures so early that PHPUnit cannot identify the content of that file as a test - as no class could be loaded up until that point.

Comment: pretty much that should be it, agreed

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today testing my controllers. Turns out just following the Book's command for it doesn't work, since PHPUnit can't find the test classes. I managed to find a workaround, just specify the test file you'd like tested, and it'll work.

```
phpunit -c app src/Acme/DemoBundle/Tests/Utility/CalculatorTest.php
```

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me that I had one extra directory level in my bundles. Instead of `MyVendorName\MyBundleNameBundle` I had `MyVendorName\MyProject\MyBundleNameBundle`

The default directories within `phpunit.xml.dist`, in the section `testsuites` are those:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
        <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

but none did match my bundle namespace: `Xmontero\Emperors\AdminBundle` whose tests, in turn, were in the directory `src/Xmontero/Emperors/AdminBundle/Tests`.

In addition ALL my bundles had that syntax and I removed any bundle with the other syntax (like `Acme\DemoBundle`). As a result, `phpunit` did not find any test.

I solved like this: just below this line in `phpunit.xml.dist`

```
<directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
```

I added this line

```
<directory>../src/*/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
```

so it reads:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
        <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        <directory>../src/*/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

...and everything worked fine ;)

-- EDIT 1 day later --

It gives me now report on coverage about the test itself, when running `phpunit -c app --coverage-html myNiceDir` - when I expect it to give me only the coverage of the system under test.

This is because there is a `whitelist` that follows the same pattern, and there is something to be added in the `exclude` list:

Where it read this:

```
<exclude>
    <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
    <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
    <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
    <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
</exclude>
```

I changed into this:

```
<exclude>
    <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
    <directory>../src/*/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
    <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
    <directory>../src/*/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
    <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
    <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
</exclude>
```

I hope now it's correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact error, and I solved by just upgrading my phpunit version, I had 3.6.10 and now I have 4.0.17 and it works perfectly and as expected.
The Synfony book is not completely wrong, it just states the wrong phpunit version as the needed one.